# Even after executing the code successfully pytest says empty suite and is not printing the print statements

Tags: python, python-3.x, automation

I am trying to run one method from a different module in pytest using import. It runs correctly but in the report it says empty suite. Its not printing the print statements.

roboForm.py -

```
import unittest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
class Roboform(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        # create a new Chrome session
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.implicitly_wait(10)
        self.driver.maximize_window()
        self.driver.get("https://www.roboform.com/filling-tests")
    def click_Custom_Form(self):
        # get the xpath of the link and page
        title = self.driver.title
        assert title== "RoboForm Form Filling Tests"
        print("We are on the right page")
        #click on custom form link
        self.custom_form = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Custom')]").click()
    def close_browser(self):
        self.driver.quit()
```

I am running the below code in pytest - test_classB.py

```
import self as self
from roboForm import Roboform
class Test():
    Roboform.setUp(self)
    print ("Browser and page launched from RoboForm")
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Custom')]").click()
    print ("Test Passed")
    Roboform.close_browser(self)
```

Getting the below error :

======================== no tests ran in 11.53 seconds ========================

Process finished with exit code 0

Empty suite

Empty suite

Comment: question related information (including updates) belong in the question not in the comments. Update your questio DO NOT put it as a comment.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse. Thank you. Updated the post.

Comment: your Roboform class doesn't contain any tests

Answer (score -1):

Agreed with @Corey Goldberg.

Try

```
def test_click_Custom_Form(self):
```

instead

```
def click_Custom_Form(self):
```